# What does the number in red near to the "Defend" menu stand for?

Tags: the-mighty-quest-for-epic-loot

I really don't understand, and hovering it won't provide any tooltip (like it sometime does with other interface elements).

[image: Number in red near the "Defend" menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number represents the number of mines and defeated heroes that are ready to be collected.  The mines do not need to be full for this, they just need to have generated some.  You can extract materials from mines/heroes by clicking on them.

[Source](https://www.themightyquest.com/en/forums/general-discussion/topics/numbernexttodefend)

Comment: Hell, that was so unclear.  Thanks for the answer !

Comment: @Anto Confused me as well.  I thought it meant players were attacking me.

Comment: Same here.  Another question: right now, the number is "7", while I only have 6 mines...  Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, got it: it also counts the dead heroes lying in your castle !  Perhaps it is worth to be included in the answer ;)